# actix-web app_data is always None in request handler

Tags: rust, actix-web

I want to register application level data when configuring Actix http server, but when I try to access the data in a request handler with `HttpRequest::app_data()` I always get `None`. The code below panics in the `index` request handler at the `expect` statement.
It does work however if I use a `String` instead of my `TestData` struct.

What am I doing wrong?

My cargo.toml:

```
[...]

[dependencies]
actix-web = "3.0"
log = "0.4"
env_logger = "0.9"
```

My code:

```rust
use actix_web::{middleware, web, HttpRequest, Result, Responder, HttpResponse};
use actix_web::{App, HttpServer};
use std::sync::Arc;
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;
extern crate env_logger;


struct TestData {
  host: String
}

pub async fn index(req: HttpRequest) -> impl Responder {
  let td: &TestData = req.app_data().expect("Test data missing in request handler.");
  td.host.clone()
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
  std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", 
                    format!("actix_server={log_level},actix_web={log_level}", 
                            log_level="DEBUG"));
  env_logger::init();

  let server_data = web::Data::new(
    TestData {
      host: "Dadada".to_string(),
    }
  );

  HttpServer::new(move || {
     App::new()
      .app_data(server_data.clone())
      .route("/", web::get().to(index))
      .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
  })
  .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
  .run()
  .await
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `Data<T>` type to `app_data` with turbo fish syntax.

```rust
pub async fn index(req: HttpRequest) -> impl Responder {
  let td: &TestData = req.app_data::<web::Data<TestData>>().expect("Test data missing in request handler.");

  td.host.clone()
}
```

If you take a look to `HttpRequest::app_data` defintion, you see that `app_data` needs this info to desambiguate the `get` call

```rust
pub fn app_data<T: 'static>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        for container in self.0.app_data.iter().rev() {
            //Used here ------------------------\/
            if let Some(data) = container.get::<T>() {
                return Some(data);
            }
        }

        None
}
```

If you only give the compiler the `td` type (`td: &TestData`). Applying coercion, the compiler will infer a `T` which respects `T: 'static` bound, but it will not be the `T` (`web::Data<TestData>`) that you want.

Comment: Nailed it, thanks. I just wonder why the compiler does not tell me that...